# Cómo usar SideMenu dentro de TabBarController Swift 5

Tags: swift

estoy creando una app, donde se usan 3 formas de navegación entre pantallas, NavigationViewController, TabBarController y necesito incorporar un menú lateral desplegable, encontré una librería que te ayuda a implementarlo https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

El problema, es que al incorporarlo en mi app, una vez que se inicia mi TabBarController, y al desplegar el SideMenu, si hago un perfomSegue(...)[navegar a otra pantalla], se pierde por completo la barra de navegación del TabBarContr.
Anexo la estructura de mi proyecto

```
                                     --> NavController --> Item0
```

NavController --> Login --> TabBarController --> NavController --> Item1

```
                                     --> NavController --> Item2
```

Después del TabBar es donde mostraría el sidemenu, y al presionar una opción, o bien puede navegar a una opción del tabBar o puede ir a otro viewController (como ir a configuración), pero no debe de perderse la barra del tabBar

Espero puedan ayudarme, y si no me expliqué del todo, háganmelo saber, para que pueda darles más recursos.

Comment: El `TabController` está embebido en un `NavigationController`?

Comment: si, el NavController es la raíz, ya que la primer pantalla es la del login, pero hay otras pantallas de registro, entonces por eso aparece promero el NavController.

Comment: Si pero también lo puedes agregar a cada controller individualmente, puedes intentar embeber los Childs del `TabController` en `NavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

Si el menú lateral esta a la derecha de la estructura debería funcionar.
NavController --> Login --> TabBarController --> NavController --> Item1 --> Menú.

Prueba a colocar un botón que pase a un nuevo ViewController, debería mantener el TabBar.

Comment: OK, pero entonces si tengo 5 views en el tabBar, tendría que agregarlo 5 veces? o sea, crear 5 segues para la vista del menú

Comment: Si lo que quieres conseguir es que el menú este en todos los items del tabBar, no sé como podrías hacerlo sin duplicar código. De todas maneras podrías evitar utilizar el tabBar y añadir esas 5 views al menú o realizar un menú a cada lado.